# How to fill a shape with different elements of varying sizes

Tags: icon, fill, script

I'm looking to replicate this effect without having to putting each icon in by hand manually. Is there a program or script that could help me achieve this?

I tried it with some mosaic apps but it didn't work out very well.

Does anyone have some ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hello Grafissimo, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please show us what you have tried and why it didn't work? We are not a tutorial-on-demand website, we ask you to show some effort and we'd rather explain where your process is wrong than give a quick step-by-step. Please [edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/105903/edit) your question to include this information. If you want to know more about this site, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) or the [help] they will get you up to speed!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate vector pattern of random dots with specific density](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95512/generate-vector-pattern-of-random-dots-with-specific-density)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace specific symbols in scatter plot in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95975/replace-specific-symbols-in-scatter-plot-in-illustrator/95998#95998)

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to Illustrator this can be done fairly easily with [Jongware's CircleFill script](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/732621).

[image: Something Like this]

Then to easily replace objects I recommend installing and using the wonderful [copyToMultipleObjects script by John Wundes](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/).

All you have to do is select one "flag circle" on the topmost layer/position above the shapes you want to replace and the script will copy it and scale it perfectly to match.

This works on anything, including bitmaps!

[image]

---

So your general workflow would look something like this:

[image]

---

To install these scripts, opposite click on the link and save it to your desktop or copy it to a notepad document and save it as "All Files" with a .js after the script name.

With Illustrator closed, navigate to your Illustrator's Script folder, which is in the following example location (the actual location will depend on your installation of Illustrator and language):

> Windows: C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Illustrator CC
>   2014/Presets/en_GB/Scripts
>
> Mac OS: Applications/Adobe/Adobe Illustrator CC
>   2014/Presets/en_GB/Scripts

And paste a copy of the .js file into the folder and open Illustrator.

Comment: Upvote for mentioning those scripts  but I'm wondering about OP's (very scant!) description of the current workflow. "Icons" suggests they are bitmaps – do they work as well?

Comment: @usr2564301Absolutly they do, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw9Nj.gif

Comment: So it does! Valentine is already over but *do* add this screencast to your answer!

Comment: @usr2564301Good point, updated the post with one.